# How to fix error in non-numeric matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have this data frame:

```
structure(list(Nazwa = c("a", "b"), Miejscowosc = c("aaa", "bbb"
), KodPocztowy = c("09-520", "44-207"), Zainstalowano = c("2020-03-20 00:00:00.000", 
"2019-02-27 00:00:00.000"), Szczytowa = c(9.14, 4.5), Latitude = c("52.550000", 
"50.101860"), Longitude = c("19.700000", "18.546640")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I read this data from the **aaa.xlsx** file.

```
points <- read_xlsx(paste0("From/",qwerty,"/aaa.xlsx"))
```

Then I try to use the code:

```
points_sp <- SpatialPoints(points[,c(6,7)], CRS("+init=EPSG:4326"))
```

Unfortunately I am getting an error:
cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix
How to solve it?

Comment: Assuming the `structure(..)` you provided is `points`, its lat/lon columns are strings; while I haven't tested it, I'd think that most spatial functions would require the coordinates to be numbers. Have you tried converting them with `points[,6:7] <- lapply(points[,6:7], as.numeric)` and trying again?

Comment: FYI, the Stack tag-recommendation system is imperfect. Please take a moment to look at the tags recommended for applicability. Here, [tag:rstudio] is wrong because this has nothing to do with the IDE itself (regardless of the programming language used within it), and I don't see how [tag:date] enters into the discussion. (The only reason [tag:matrix] is relevant is because the error says "matrix", and that's because internally it is converting the arguments into a matrix *internally*, otherwise that tag is really just a red herring.) [tag:frame] means nothing to me, [tag:dataframe]?.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert the character strings to numeric and the `tbl_df` to a matrix or plain data frame:

```
points$Latitude <- as.numeric(points$Latitude)
points$Longitude <- as.numeric(points$Longitude)
points_sp <- SpatialPoints(as.data.frame(points[,c(6,7)]), CRS("+init=EPSG:4326"))
points_sp
SpatialPoints:
#      Latitude Longitude
# [1,] 52.55000  19.70000
# [2,] 50.10186  18.54664
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```